# Is the light impact on universe expansion is neglectable?

Tags: visible-light, momentum, conservation-laws, astrophysics, stars

Imagine a universe with the below properties in a present time.

- It has only two stars
- The stars are located 1 light-year apart
- The stars have the same properties as our sun today.
- The stars are at rest, having a relative speed of 0
- The space in this universe does not expand, but other laws of physics are identical to our universe

After a billion years, what will be the relative speed between those stars? Will the light emitted by those stars will be able to set them in motion?

Comment: Neglecting gravitational forces, the light sail effect each would have on the other would be miniscule at 1 light year, but not 0

Comment: @AdrianHoward, how to calculate it for my example?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring their gravitational attraction. Why?

Comment: @G.Smith, yeah, you are right; it should not be ignored. Do you think there is a point at which the light sail forces overcome the gravitational forces?

Comment: No, I don’t think so. Try using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_luminosity) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure) to estimate the ratio of the light-pressure repulsion to the gravitational attraction between two stars.

Comment: @G.Smith tnx, can you please help me with calculating the energy delivered to the stars? I don't understand this part from wiki.

Comment: A star continuously radiates some number of watts into space. This goes out in all directions. At any distance away, you can get the watts per square meter ($I$) by dividing by the surface area of a big sphere around the star. This flux of energy causes pressure $I/c$ on the other star. To estimate the force, multiply that pressure by the cross sectional area of the other star.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so wikipedia gives the pressure on a surface at distance $R$ as:
$$ P(R) = \frac{1361 \text{W/m}^2}{c} \Big(\frac{1\text{AU}}{R} \Big)^2 \approx 4.5 ~\mu\text{N}\times \Big(\frac{1\text{AU}}{R} \Big)^2, $$
where $1 \text{AU}$ is the astronomical unit. From this, you get the force $F = P\times A_\odot = P\times \pi R_\odot^2$ and thus the acceleration from $F=ma$. Then its a small step to the velocity after one year. Change in distance can be neglected since the stars effectively do not move.

Note, however, that the force of the gravitational field is much larger:
$$ F_G = G \frac{M_\odot^2}{(1 \text{ly})^2} \approx 3\times 10^{18} \text{N} $$
than the force from radiation pressure. (The acceleration is still tiny, though... $M_\odot$ *is* a large number.)